# Private chat application in laravel

Tags: database, laravel, chat

How to implement database for private chat system between user and admin

ok,I have two table one is admin and second one is users

```
admin table

| id | name | email| phone_number | password |

user table
| id | name | email| phone_number | password |
```

Now How can I set up chats table between these two users??

```
chats table 
id | user_to | user_from | messsag |
```

How chat table should look like??

Comment: But.. you just answered your question. didn't you?

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz I dont think it will work out because its between two tables,May be I need better suggestion.

Comment: you should combine admin table and user table into one and just add a single filed to know if the user is admin or not.

Answer (score 1):

There is no need of using two different tables of users. Just need to add a new field in `user table` to point out if the user is admin or not. Then you `chat table` logic will work

```
user table
| id | name | email| phone_number | password | admin (true | false)

chats table 
id | user_to | user_from | messsag |
```

Alternatively you can go with a workaround like this:

```
admin table

| id | name | email| phone_number | password |

user table
| id | name | email| phone_number | password |

chats table 
id | user_to_table | user_to | user_from_table | user_from | messsag |
```